# Why can' t I run ./toolchain.py while building my kivy app on MacOS?

Tags: python, ios, macos, kivy, building

I've been following this tutorial about building app for iOS. I'm currently stuck on this moment of video:
https://youtu.be/UAi3PG-qN2k?t=414

When I input:
**sudo ./toolchain.py build python3 openssl kivy**

My terminal returns:

**sudo: ./toolchain.py: command not found**
or **./toolchain.py: Permission denied** when I don't add sudo at the beginning

I don't know what to do. Could you guys help me? I'm new with MacOS
My MacOS is ***High Sierra*** and I downloaded ***Xcode 10.1***

Thank you for help!

Comment: Have you verified that toolchain.py is an executable?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Look up tutorials on file permissions and how to change them.
It looks like you have no working knowledge of how your file system works and you should look for entry level introduction to using the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently following the same tutorial. In newer versions of macOS/Xcode, you can just use `$ toolchain` rather than the full `$ ./toolchain.py` so long as you have the Xcode Command Line Tools installed. The rest of the `build` command that follows is the same.

Follow this page for the updated guide:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios

**EDIT:**
I came across the same error when rebuilding python3 kivy. Check to make sure that you've installed `kivy-ios==master` and NOT the pip3 version (it's very outdated):

`$ pip3 uninstall kivy-ios`

`$ git clone git://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios`

Then you should be able to run: `$ sudo python ./toolchain.py build python3 kivy`

Let me know if you're still having issues.